# Ajax success issue with React and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I've got a form that I am trying to handle with React. This is the ajax method in the handleSubmit function:

```
$.ajax({
  data: formData,
  dataType: "json",
  url: '/requests',
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log('SHOW HERE ON RESPONSE');
    this.setState({
      formSubmitted: true
    });
  }
});
```

When I click on submit, I can see the POST request go through and the server responds with a 200. But the success callback is never entered, I don't see the console message.

My rails controller's action is just a simple:

```
return render nothing: true, status: 200 if request.xhr?
```

The log with the server response includes:

```
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

However when I move the stuff from the success callback in the ajax request to a `complete` callback then I see this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this error, because `this` behaves differently inside `$.ajax()`'s `success` callback, because jQuery uses it internally.

Suppose you are executing the following `ajax` call in response to a click function, then:

```
var $this = $(this);
$.ajax({
  data: formData,
  dataType: "json",
  url: '/requests',
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log('SHOW HERE ON RESPONSE');
      $this.setState({
      formSubmitted: true
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In the callback, `this` refers to the `jqXHR` object of the ajax call, instead of the context you expect (in this case, the component you're calling `setState` on).

`$.ajax` allows you to set the context explicitly to avoid these types of conflicts.

```
$.ajax({
  data: formData,
  dataType: "json",
  url: '/requests',
  type: "POST",
  context: this,
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log('SHOW HERE ON RESPONSE');
    this.setState({
      formSubmitted: true
    });
  }
});
```

Adding `context: this` will fix this issue.